# Auto click "place order" button in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a custom jquery function that is intended to click the "place order" button on checkout if there is a `?` (query) in url. The Product price is zero(0) due to a coupon applied to this and I removed the terms and conditions box.

But if I click the "place order" button with the function, then it redirects to payment gateway; on the other hand, if I manually click the "place order" button it goes to the "Thank you" page.

Any idea as to how I can solve this? Here is the function I am using:

```
if (location.search === '?add-to-cart=406') {
jQuery('#place_order').click();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
if (location.search === '?add-to-cart=406') {
 jQuery( "#place_order" ).trigger( "click" );
}
```